# Executable console java app to service on Mac

Tags: macos, jar

I have a jar file an console app, I need to make it a service on mac osx which should run perioducally, how can I do that?

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an entry for the rund using lingon.  You can get lingon here  http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/

Comment: Lingon is a good GUI helper over launchd/launchctl - The command line command you would use is launchctl which is part of OSX